# Using the auto keyword in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm just using a simple code that uses auto:

```
double **PArrays = new double*[3];

count = 0;
for(auto Array: PArrays)
    {
        Array = new double[6];
        for(int i{}; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {

                Array[i] = i;
                std::cout<<"The value of Array i is: "<<Array[i]<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"The value of PArray is: "<<PArrays[count][i];
            }
            else if(count == 1)
            {
                Array[i] = i * i;
            }
            else
            {
                Array[i] = i * i * i;               
            }
        }
        count += 1;
    }
```

I can't figure out why the values in the PArray[i][j], given that [i][j] are within bounds, results in the value of zero.

Furthermore, the compiler complains, it says that 'begin' was not declared in scope and then points to Array auto variable in the for loop, also, points to the same variable saying 'end' was not declared. :

```
for(auto Array: PArrays)
    {
        for(auto x: Array)
        {
            std::cout<<"The value is: "<<x;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: `auto Array: PArrays` This makes a copy, you probably want `auto& Array`. Suggested viewing: [CppCon 2014: Scott Meyers "Type Deduction and Why You Care"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU)

Comment: What is the declaration of `PArrays`?

Comment: Not sure you can rely on `int i{}` to initialise it to 0 on all platforms

Comment: @IlBeldus: From C++11, you can.

Comment: @aschepler, I added that(sorry, I missed it);

Comment: The `range_expression` in a  [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) requires "either an array or an object for which begin and end member functions or free functions are defined". So, this code shouldn't compile, how are you getting to run it?

Comment: Nothing "results in the value of zero" if your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @aschepler Precisely...

Answer (score 8):

`for(auto Array: PArrays)` gives you a *value* copy of every element in `PArrays`. So any changes you make in `Array` will not be reflected in the original container `PArrays`.

If you want `Array` to be a *reference* to an element of `PArrays`, then use

`for(auto& Array: PArrays)`

instead.

Comment: This assumes `PArrays` is a collection of pointers (possibly smart pointers).   It won't necessarily help the second set of loops in the original post compile though - a `double *`, for example, does not have a defined `end()`.

Comment: @Bathsheba, is it true that, we can't use the range based for loop for elements on the heap?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: no that is not true.

Comment: @Bathsheba, check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/6n8koo/why_is_this_specific_declaration_giving_me_an/

Comment: That's essentially due to decay of the type to a pointer, not the heap per se. You ought to ask a clarifying question on this site. I'll look out for it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: All the more reason for asking a question.